# Laravel Eloquent methods inside View

Tags: php, view, model, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two models called `Product` and `ProductImage`. I also have a view where i want to list all products with their related `ProductImage` where the attribute `main_image` is equal to `1`. In the `ProductController` i call the method `all()` of the model `Product` and store it in the `data` array of the view so that i can loop trough the products inside the view. But inside that loop i want to show the related main image of that product. Can i do this by calling the Eloquent methods like `where()` and `first` etc. inside the View?

Greetings,

Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need: http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/

Only for you the relation will look like this:

```
public function mainImage()
{
  return $this->hasOne('ProductImage')->where('main_image', 1);
}
```

then you can simply do something like this:

```
// fetch
$products = Product::with('mainImage')->paginate(10);

// output
@foreach($products as $product)
  ...
  <img src="{{ $product->mainImage->url }}" />
  ...
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your ProductImage entity has a foreign key to your Product entity. So, Product can have multiple ProductImage.

In your Product model, you can add this:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('ProductImage');
}
```

And in your view:

```
@foreach($product->images as $image)
    // Do what you want.
@endforeach
```

I hope I understand your question.

Comment: But if i want to use a where statement on the image can i also do this inside the view? Like `$product->images()->where() as $image`.

Comment: I think the view is not the place where you should use a where statement. If you have to do a specific treatment, you should make a function for it in the model and call it in the controller to pass the result to the view that will only display it. It's my opinion on how to use MVC, but maybe there is a more correct way to do this.

Comment: So in my model i have to create a method like `scopeAllProductsWithImages` and make an inner join inside that method?

Comment: You can use manual join to achieve what you need, but you can also get the most of the framework and use a helper relation that lets you eager load the image you need. Check my answer for details.